# Adding Comments to a Vlookup Database

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using vlookup to pull from a database. But here's the catch, I want an editable comments section that will update the database itself.

So, I can easily 'pull' the previous comments with a line like

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,'Database'!A2:E587,6)
```

However, now, I want to add information TO that line. For example, let's say that line currently says "Is orange and smells like feet" but now the user who pulled up the record wants to add "And it's shaped like a bat"

I'm thinking I'll need a vba loop for this.

Ideas? Even a reference page I can go to would be awesome.

Thank you.

EDIT: For posterity's reference, the full coding solution provided by Tim is detailed below.

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim retrieve As Range, update As Range

    Set retrieve = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B5,B19"), Target)
    Set update = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("H5,H19"), Target)

    If Not retrieve Is Nothing Then
        Retrieve_Comments Targ:=retrieve
    ElseIf Not update Is Nothing Then
        Update_Comments update
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Retrieve_Comments(ByRef Targ As Range)

    Dim c As Range, id, f As Range, cmt

    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'need to disable events so you don't trigger the update sub...
    For Each c In Targ.Cells
        id = c.Value
        Set f = Sheets("Database").Columns(1).Find(id, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            cmt = f.Offset(0, 5).Value
        Else
            cmt = "???"
        End If
        c.Offset(0, 6).Value = cmt
    Next c

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub Update_Comments(rng As Range)
    Dim f As Range, id, cmt

    'no need to disable events here, since you're updating a different sheet
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        id = c.EntireRow.Cells(2).Value
        cmt = c.Value
        Set f = Sheets("Database").Columns(1).Find(id, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 5).Value = cmt
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare bones outline:

```
Sub AddToComment()
    Dim f as Range, id, cmt

    id = selection.cells(1).entirerow.cells(1).value  ' "key" value
    cmt = selection.cells(1).entirerow.cells(5).value ' new additional comment

    Set f = sheets("database").columns(1).find(id, _
                     lookin:=xlValues,lookat:=xlwhole)
    if not f is nothing then
        with f.entirerow.cells(5)
            .value=.value & " " & cmt
        end with
    else
        msgbox "Key value '" & id & "' not found!" 
    end if

end sub
```

Comment: I've tried variations of this over the last day since you posted, and for some reason it can't seem to find the id... When I use an equation with =vlookup it works without a hitch, but this (and other variations) always give me a not found or N/A error.

Comment: if you add `Debug.Print id` is the value what you expect?

Comment: Yep, it is. :/ If I do something like Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B5,'Database'!A2:E587,6)" then it 'works' but not with Application.VLookup or find

Comment: Update on seeing the actual file: the `Find()` was failing due to extra spaces padding the values in the column being searched.